# How can I get a tag (or some look-like) with the max() value function with Python?

Tags: python, max

I'm learning Python right now and I'm trying to get a diferent result from the max() function.

The trouble I want to resolve it's the following:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

print(
    max(a,b,c)
    )
```

When I execute this sample of code I get the maximum value of the three included in the parameters of the max func, but instead I would want to obtain the name of the largest variable or maybe a tag associated with each var.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Why don't you share what it is you are trying to achieve by getting the variable name, and there is almost certainly a better way to solve the problem.

Comment: "Name of the variable" is not a reasonable thing to ask for here - all that the ``max()`` function receives are *values*, there's no particular requirement that any value even came from a variable (and the value has no connection to the variable, even if it came from one).  You've got a couple of answers already, I'll mention for completeness that the popular ``numpy`` package contains a ``argmax()`` function that returns the index of the maximum instead of its value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a dictionary instead.

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 42, 'c': 3}
>>> max(d, key=d.get)
'b'
```

Answer (score 2):

### The fastest way of doing this:

This, oddly varies based on the version of Python you're using.

### Python 2.7

**Max, zip method**

```
print(max(zip(tag.values(),tag))[1])
```

Clocked at:
20,000 Values : `0.010999917984`

***[Fastest]* Max with tag.get**

```
max(tag, key=tag.get)
```

Clocked at:
20,000 Values : `0.00600004196167`

**Max with lambda**

```
max(tag, key=lambda k: tag[k])
```

Clocked at:
20,000 Values : `0.00699996948242`

### Python 3.6

***[Fastest]* Max, zip method**

```
print(max(zip(tag.values(),tag))[1])
```

Clocked at:
20,000 Values : `0.003000020980834961`

**Max with tag.get**

```
max(tag, key=tag.get)
```

Clocked at:
20,000 Values : `0.00300025939941406257`

**Max with lambda**

```
max(tag, key=lambda k: tag[k])
```

Clocked at:
20,000 Values : `0.005000114440917969`

Comment: I was shocked that the original version of `max(zip(tag.values(),tag))[1]` while not very pythonic was significantly faster than the more pythonic `max(tag, key=tag.get)` (which is marginally faster than the `lambda` version) - Py3.6

Comment: @StefanPochmann I updated it, thanks for the input, I was just being dumb.

Answer (score 1):

Build a dictionary of name or tag -> variable pairs. Then `max` the dictionary, using the `key=function` parameter of [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=max#max).

```
a=1
b=5
c=3

d = {'a':a, 'b':b, 'c':c}

print(max(d, key=lambda k: d[k]))
```